# Google Analytics script doesn't send tracking beacons

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In jspx file I have js script for tracking sign in providers (user are signing in by email, facebook or twitter).

```
var statsAnalytics = "${jndiSettings['statsAnalytics']}";

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', statsAnalytics]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

var providerId = '${providerId}';

if (providerId) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Sign in', providerId, 'Signed in with ' + providerId]);
}
```

After debugging with GA debugger for Chrome I'm getting:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-xxxxxxx-x]":  [VM] ga_debug.js (9935):24
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  [VM] ga_debug.js (9935):24
Track Pageview [VM] ga_debug.js (9935):24
_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: "[Sign in,facebook,Signed in with facebook]":  [VM] ga_debug.js (9935):24
Track Event
```

**Why doesn't my script send tracking beacons?**

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: @Blexy unfortunately no, site is not publicly accessible

Comment: Are you seeing any data coming through Real-time reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled blocking adds with AddBlock and now it works!